# valor del campo de texto no sea mayor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando controlar un campo (valor bruto y valor neto) es evidente que el valor bruto ha de ser mayor que el neto, cuando el usuario introduce sus datos en un formulario.

En el js lo he intentado de varias maneras pero no consigo controlarlo para que en el formulario aparezca un mensaje de 'El valor tiene que ser menor que el valor bruto'.

- Seria algo como  if ($('#neto').val('uno') > $('#bruto').val('dos')) entonces mensaje error.

---

```
    $(document).on('submit','#UserForm',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loader').show();
    var data = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        method :'POST',
        url: baseUrl+'common/SaveUser',
        data:data,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            bootstrap_alert.success(sucessEnviado,'#validator');
        },
        complete: function(){
             $('#loader').hide();
             $('#horas').val('');
             $('#old').val('');
             $('#bruto').val('');
             $('#neto').val('');
             $('#visitas').val('');
             $('#suscr').val('');
             $('#canales').val('');
             $('#seguidor').val('');  
             $('#nom').val('');
             $('#register_email').val('');
             
             setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace(baseUrl+"valoracion");
                }, 2000);
             
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(thrownError);}
    });
});
```

Comment: Luego del prevent default debes poner ese if en el cual si la condicion es cierta debes setear el placeholder del input a la frase que indique el error y hacer un return para q no se ejecute la peticion.       Por cierto no debe ir ningun valor dentro de val() y asegurate que el input neto y bruto sean de tipo number

Comment: Lo hice asi pero no contempló la condicion.                   if ($('#neto').val('') > $('#bruto').val('')) {
   bootstrap_alert.success('Valor neto no puede ser mayor','#acceptmsg');
   return();
  }

Comment: Y si son valores enteros en la base de datos, y en el form son   <input type="number"

Comment: Si son enteros usa parseint y si tienen decimales parse float

Comment: lo siento no funciona

Comment: pudiste solucionar algo?

Answer (score 1):

No lo voy a hacer con tu ejemplo porque no tengo los datos, pero te dejo un ejemplo simple para que puedas darte cuenta y adaptarlo a tu trabajo.

HTML:

```
<form id="formulario">
  <input name="neto" type="number" placeholder="neto">
  <input name="bruto" type="number" placeholder="bruto">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 </form>

<p id="respuesta"></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const $form = document.getElementById('formulario');
  const $respuesta = document.getElementById('respuesta');

  $form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   let neto = e.target[0].value;
   let bruto = e.target[1].value;
   if(neto == 0 || bruto == 0){
    $respuesta.innerText = "Neto o bruto no pueden ser 0";
    return false;
   }
   if(neto >= bruto){
    $respuesta.innerText = "El valor neto no puede ser mayor que el bruto";
    return false;
   } else $respuesta.innerText = "Ok, el neto es menor";
  })
```

como funciona?: hago 2 constantes, $form que seria el formulario y $respuesta que es una simple etiqueta P donde meto la respuesta (hubiera trabajado igual console.log())
Luego le pongo un eventoo de escucha al formulario, esto es cuando clickees en enviar el evento se dispara. El preventdefault() sirve para suspender el envio tradicional del formulario y tomar el control con javascript. Luego asigno a las variables neto y bruto el valor que tienen los inputs.
Te explicoo un poco lo del e.target: e es el evento disparado, en este caso submit y e.target es quien lo disparo, en este caso el formulario. Luego o e.target[0] seria el input neto (es el primer elemento hijo del form) y el bruto seria el segundo elemento hijo.. Al almacenar el value en ambas variables estoy almacenado lo que escribi (lo cual no hay necesidad de convertir ya que son campos de tipo number). Luego hago las comparaciones y asunto arreglado.

Espero te sirva. Saludos!!

Comment: if($('#bruto').val() < ($('#neto').val())) 
 {
  $('#loader').hide();
  bootstrap_alert.success(sucessBruto,'#validator');
  return;
 }

Comment: Encontre la solucion, el problema lo tenia en el popup que tenia que decir "El valor neto no puede ser mayor que el bruto" y siempre que apretaba el boton de aceptar para que validase y comparase los dos campos (neto >bruto) se quedaba 'pillado' la condicion que ponia estaba bien su codigo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al final acabe con esto y lo tengo solucionado. El problema estaba en el popup que me avisaba cuando ocurria el error del (neto > bruto).

> if($('#bruto').val() < ($('#neto').val()))   {       $('#loader').hide();
> bootstrap_alert.success(sucessBruto,'#validator');      return;     }